# Can't Configure Sublime Text for Python 3 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3

I wanted to configure sublime text for python 3 on my Mac but it did not work even after I followed every instructions on my tutorial.

I first found out the full path to my Python interpreter by entering`type -a python3`in the terminal, and the terminal returned this:

```
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Then I created a new build system in Sublime Text and created a new build named “*Python3.sublime-build* ”, the codes are as followed:

```
{
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```

It is the path that the terminal returned to me but when I tried to run a program, the console returned error to me:

```
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u', '']]
[dir: /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I don't know if this is because I reinstalled python3 earlier on and did not delete all the previous symbolic files/frameworks. Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: No, this is because you didn't save your file before building. Next time, try googling the error before posting a question.

Comment: I just figured, thx. Pretty new to Python :P